# how to password protect dropdown Picker javascript

Tags: reactjs, react-native, dropdown, react-native-dropdown-picker

How can I secure TextEntry={true} to dropdown selected items in React native

```
 const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    {label: 'Apple', value: 'apple'},
    {label: 'Banana', value: 'banana'}
  ]);

<DropDownPicker
      open={open}
      value={value}
      items={items}
      setOpen={setOpen}
      setValue={setValue}
      setItems={setItems}
    />
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "password protect" a dropdown picker component? What is `TextEntry`? What is the issue and what are you expecting?

Comment: You could map the `items` array to the array of values you want to render/display, and for the item element value matching the `value` state update its `label` value to be `"*****"`.

Comment: Correct. That is why you map the unmasked items to an array where you mask the selected value. Though it's not really clear what the use case is. If a person knows the unmasked values before selection then it would be trivial to know the value of the masked values after selection.

Comment: It would be something like `items={items.map(el => el.value === value ? { ...el, label: el.label.replaceAll(/./g, '*') } : el)}`.

Comment: Did you tried labelProps as in the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map the dropdown items to a new array where the currently selected `value` is masked.

Example:

```
export default function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([
    { label: 'Apple', value: 'apple' },
    { label: 'Banana', value: 'banana' },
  ]);

  return (
    <DropDownPicker
      open={open}
      items={items.map((el) =>
        el.value === value
          ? { ...el, label: el.label.replace(/./g, '*') }
          : el
      )}
      setOpen={setOpen}
      setValue={setValue}
      setItems={setItems}
    />
  );
}
```

[Expo Snack Demo](https://snack.expo.dev/@drew.w.reese/how-to-password-protect-dropdown-picker-javascript)

[image]
[image]

Comment: If here you see When person select Apple its change into ****** but I just want to change this Select an item to apple as *****

Comment: Like in simple dropdown when we click on select an item it show us item and replace name select item with that select value in Our case it is Apple so I need to just show that as *****

Comment: @ToxicMani I don't understand what you are saying. Is that not what the code is doing? Changing the selected option from "apple" to "*****" when "apple" is selected? I've even included screen captures.

Comment: Ok let me try this

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this using labelProps

```
labelProps={{
 TextEntry={true} 
}}
```